# Random number generation on Spartan-3E

Tags: hardware, random, verilog, fpga

I need to generate pseudo-random numbers for my genetic algorithm on a Spartan-3E FPGA and i want to implement it in verilog: could you give me any pointers on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you'd use the [IEEE.math_real](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/help/VHDL/stdpkg.html) uniform function

```
use IEEE.math_real.all;
procedure UNIFORM (variable Seed1,Seed2:inout integer; variable X:out real);
```

But do a tiny bit a research on pseudo random number generators (PRNGs) and you'll find many variants that are simple [LFSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register)'s - which look remarkably similar to CRC generators.

Here are several resources if you want to roll your own starting from existing, working PRNGs:

http://www.opencores.org/?do=project&who=systemc_rng

http://verificationguild.com/modules.php?name=Downloads&d_op=viewdownload&cid=3

Here's a CRC VHDL code generator:

http://www.easics.be/webtools/crctool

Comment: The OP wanted verilog - but your suggestion to look at LFSRs is sound. 

Just for my own interest, is that UNIFORM procedure synthesizable?  What does it synthesize to?

Answer (score 16):

Of course the random generator by Adam is not synthesizable! You have to explicitly create an [LFSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LFSR).

Following example might help. It is an 8-bit maximal LFSR

```
module lfsr(input clk, reset, en, output reg [7:0] q);
  always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
    if (reset)
      q <= 8'd1; // can be anything except zero
    else if (en)
      q <= {q[6:0], q[7] ^ q[5] ^ q[4] ^ q[3]}; // polynomial for maximal LFSR
  end
endmodule;
```

Answer (score 9):

You've already got some good answers, but I'll just point out the canonical guide to LFSRs in FPGAs is here:

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp052.pdf

It's a bit Xilinx specific in places (which is OK for your FPGA :) but the principles are transferable to others.

Answer (score 3):

There is an online tool that can generate Verilog or VHDL code for a pseudo-random number generator. It's on [OutputLogic.com](http://OutputLogic.com)

Answer (score 2):

The pointer above to OpenCores has a file in the verilog folder called: [rng.v](http://opencores.org/project,systemc_rng)

I have used it in a Spartan-3AN and it works great. My code used the random number generator to select a random PWM after I programmed the part and it covered all the selectable PWMs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the LFSR.  I have made one before and it is used for encryption.

Comment: I think it's important to note here that LFSRs are useful for pseudo-random number generation, but they are inappropriate for use in real encryption schemes.