# How to generate pseudo random number in FPGA?

Tags: random, fpga

How to generate pseudo random number in FPGA?

Comment: For those doing searches for random numbers in FPGA, they will be able to far more easily find this question. Thus, I won't vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Perhaps those who are looking for FPGA in stackoverflow would like to know about a specific site : [Logic Design proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20632/logic-design?referrer=YVw0qLaS2iiFAaI1gMp5oQ2)

Comment: oh, good that it was asked here and not in this Area 51 site. It was DELETED ;)

Answer (score 7):

This has been covered (I'd go for an LFSR):
[Random number generation on Spartan-3E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757151/random-number-generation-on-spartan-3e)

Answer (score 5):

There's an excellent Xilinx application note on generating pseudo-random number sequences efficiently in an FPGA. It's [XAPP052](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp052.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

If it's not for cryptography or other applications with an intelligent adversary (e.g. gambling) I'd use a [linear feedback shift register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) approach.

It only uses exclusive or and shift, so it is very simple to implement in hardware.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, LFSRs can be used for pseudo random numbers in an FPGA. Here is a VHDL implementation of a maximal length 32-bit LFSR.

```
process(clk)

  -- maximal length 32-bit xnor LFSR based on xilinx app note XAPP210
  function lfsr32(x : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)) return std_logic_vector is
  begin
    return x(30 downto 0) & (x(0) xnor x(1) xnor x(21) xnor x(31));
  end function;

begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if rst='1' then
      pseudo_rand <= (others => '0');
    else
      pseudo_rand <= lfsr32(psuedo_rand);
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```