# How to generate random numbers in FPGA for use as IV in cryptographic applications

Tags: random, cryptography, initialization, fpga, lfsr

I am looking for a way to generate random numbers in FPGA for use as an IV for cryptographic applications. However, the answers to similar questions i found on Stackoverflow so far generate random numbers from a "Fixed SEED" which is not at all suitable for a cryptographic application. Pointers to two of such answers are as follows:-

[Random number generation on Spartan-3E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757151/random-number-generation-on-spartan-3e)
and 
[How to generate pseudo random number in FPGA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125640/how-to-generate-pseudo-random-number-in-fpga)

Hope to get some helpful answers in this regard from the community!
Thanks

Comment: Try this: *[Compact FPGA-based True and Pseudo Random Number Generators](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.444.6979&rep=rep1&type=pdf)*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is a development Q/A site - this doesn't include FPGA design. Why not try [EE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fpga)?

Comment: So, an [unfixed seed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZeRF.jpg) and an appeal to an authoritarian source ([Approved Random Number Generators for FIPS PUB 140 - 2, Security Requirements for Cryptographic Modules](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips140-2/fips1402annexc.pdf))? (Leads to [NIST Special Publication 800 -90A  Revision 1  Recommendation for Random  Number Generation Using  Deterministic Random Bit Generators](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-90Ar1.pdf)).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you need some random entropy in order to generate a cryptographically secure pseudo number generator (CSPRNG). That generally is obtained by using portions of real-time events from am OS which may include interrupt timing and other hard things that are hard for am attacker to influence.

A FPGA in isolation is not going to have this source of entropy.

There are also several ways to create True Random Numbers Generators such as using multiple free running oscillators.